# Why $x^3+iy^3$ Is Not Differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

> $f(z)=x^3+iy^3$
>
> Find where is function is differentiable/analytic

$u(x,y)=x^3,v(x,y)=y^3$

$u_{x}=3x^2=3y^2=v_{y}$

$u_{y}=0=-0=-v_x$

So for all $(\pm x,\pm y)$ $C-R$ equations are satisfied.

So the function is differentiable at those points?

Comment: Why are C-R equations satisfied? Clearly $u_x \not=v_y$ for when $x^2\not= y^2$. EDIT: So it will be satisfied which implies $x=y$ or $x=-y$.

Comment: I got $x^2=y^2$ it is true for $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$?

Comment: "So for all $(\pm x,\pm y)$ $C-R$ equations are satisfied." You mean: "So, at every point $t\pm it$, Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied", right?

Comment: @Did Yes that what I meant

Comment: Thus correct your post? (I thought this was obviously my point to suggest this, but apparently...)

Comment: Well, it is  $\mathbb R$-differentiable,  but not $\mathbb   C$-differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
x=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}
\qquad
y=\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}
$$
the function can be written as
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{8}\bigl((z+\bar{z})^3-(z-\bar{z})^3\bigr)=
\frac{1}{4}(3z^2\bar{z}+\bar{z}^3)
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}=
\frac{1}{4}\left(
6z\bar{z}+3\bar{z}h+3h\bar{h}+6z\bar{h}+
(3z^2+3\bar{z}^2+3\bar{z}\bar{h}+\bar{h}^2)\frac{\bar{h}}{h}
\right)
$$
and the limit for $h\to0$ exists only if $z^2+\bar{z}^2=0$, that is, $y^2=x^2$ or $y=\pm x$.

You can't write $(\pm x,\pm y)$: the solution consists of the points of the form $x+ix$ or $x-ix$, for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

The function is differentiable at those points, but nowhere analytic (it is differentiable on no open set).